# How to share Data Between Two Steps in same Spring batch jobs -JAVA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I am using Spring batch jobs and in single batch job have reader processor and writer.

What I need to do is
in step one, in reader need to fetch some data from db with some conditions, lets say I got 3 IDS

In next step need to fetch data with result of 1st reader results (that means with resultant of 3 ID's , need to fetch some results with some more condition from db )

Suggest some methods how to share the data between ItemReaders

Comment: how would you do it in any other process? store it in a file, store it somewhere in a List, ...

Comment: we can do by making the complex sql query in single step

Comment: Have you tried `CacheManager`?

Comment: Shouldn't that be in 1 step instead of 2 steps? Feels more like read-process-write. Why transfer to a next step?

Comment: Query has sub query, time taken to run query is higher than using steps. I guess( i am not sure)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.